# Is there a way to move controls in the visual tree? (WPF)

Tags: wpf, visual-tree

I want to relocate some controls from one part in the visual tree to another.

- can I do this?
- and direction or hint on how to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply remove the control from its parent, and then add it to the new parent.

Comment: Yeah, that was my guess to, but I somehow seem to miss a good way how. I'm probably using the wrong types...

Comment: You can remove and add items through a panel's Children collection, if it's a button or something else, then through Content.  Also, if your element's aren't named for easy access then you can use the VisualTreeHelper to help you obtain the children/parent you want to move/move from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.visualtreehelper.aspx

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use Insert, this way you are able to choose exactly where its index is in the visual tree.

Comment: Can you please comment it more?